# How long does it take for a Firefox extension to be reviewed for public release?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

About 2 weeks ago I nominated a Firefox Extension I made for public release. It seemed stable enough and received a number of positive reviews, so the time felt right.

I haven't heard anything from Mozilla yet; how long should I expect to be waiting before things progress?

Thanks!

Comment: you should make it wiki, if you want any chance for it to stay open

Comment: Why would this question need to be a wiki?

Comment: @pc1oad1etter-because its not programming related and there is no discrete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your add-on does, I've seen it take several months.  This longer timeframe generally applies to site-specific add-ons though.

Your best bet is to e-mail amo-editors@mozilla.org to ask for an estimate with a link to your add-on.